# How do I search the gem with specific version and platform

Tags: ruby, docker, rubygems, bundler

I encountered problem that the `sorbet-static:0.5.10346-x86_64-linux` couldn't install with either `bundle install` and `gem install sorbet-static:0.5.10346 --platform x86_64-linux` in `ruby:2.5.1` x86_64 docker container.

So I'm want to check availability of the sorbet-static gem with specific version and platform in a docker container.

Problem part

```
FROM ruby:2.5.1
# To be able to install old packages from archive.
ADD ./docker/web/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential nodejs && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
ENV APP_PATH /opt/app
WORKDIR $APP_PATH
ADD Gemfile $APP_PATH
ADD Gemfile.lock $APP_PATH
ADD gems $APP_PATH/gems
RUN bundle install --jobs `expr $(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -c "cpu cores") - 1` --retry 3
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Could not find sorbet-static-0.5.10346-x86_64-linux in any of the sources
```

I have tried below commands, however results are not useful.

I got the latest version.

```
gem search sorbet-static
```

I got results that is too many combination of versions and platforms.

```
gem search sorbet-static --all
```

Comment: Please provide content of your `docker/web/sources.list`.

Comment: Is there a reason that you are using the 2.5.1 image? Could you use a newer base image?

Comment: Is there a reason that you are using the 0.5.10346 version of sorbet-static? Often the sorbet-static maintainer release several new versions per week and your version is already more than one and a half years old, which is ancient for the sorbet-static gem. And according to Rubygems there have been more than 10_000 newer versions released since then.

Comment: The reason is I have joined to a running project. I want to prepare the project to be able to develop new feature.
`docker/web/sources.list` has archive repository settings like datawookie.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM ruby:2.5.1

RUN echo "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free" > /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    echo "deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN apt-get update -qq && \
    apt-get install -y build-essential nodejs && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ADD Gemfile .

RUN bundle install --jobs `expr $(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -c "cpu cores") - 1` --retry 3
```

`Gemfile`

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'sorbet-static', '0.5.10346'
```

Screenshot below confirms that the version you require has been installed.

[image]

Comment: The OP asked specifically about checking the availability of the `0.5.10346-x86_64-linux` version of the gem and installing it.

Comment: Updated with correct version.